# Which highstock options can I use to remove inbetween xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm implementing highstock line graph in my app and facing difficulty to fix the xAxis.

Eventhough the data is daily, there are "hour" at 12:00 between nodes.

[image]

Which option can I use to remove those inbetween "12:00" xAxis? I have tried several options from the doc http://api.highcharts.com/highstock but the results are same.

My series data are :

```
    [
      {
        "name": "check",
        "data": [
          [
            1460505600000,
            778475
          ],
          [
            1460592000000,
            778031
          ],
          [
            1460678400000,
            802150
          ],
          [
            1460764800000,
            700420
          ],
          [
            1460851200000,
            641872
          ],
          [
            1460937600000,
            778706
          ],
          [
            1461024000000,
            227841
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "okay",
        "data": [
          [
            1460505600000,
            440160
          ],
          [
            1460592000000,
            419736
          ],
          [
            1460678400000,
            406018
          ],
          [
            1460764800000,
            394896
          ],
          [
            1460851200000,
            407884
          ],
          [
            1460937600000,
            422041
          ],
          [
            1461024000000,
            146392
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: How to do that?
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/xka7caun/) check here

Comment: @yongsup `tickInterval` is the hint. I appreciate your anwer. Thank you so much! :bow:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) as 24 * 3600 * 1000 (one day in milisecods).

```
xAxis: {
   tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is the answer. Thank you so much! :bow: :bow: :bow: